# Can pnpm replace npm link // yarn link?

Tags: npm, pnpm

npm link and yarn link are both "not the best". I run into issues with them quite often. Now I have read about pnpm and its local storage. I wonder if pnpm can help me remedy my npm link issues in the following case:

I have two projects in separate repos, and therefore not in one single workspace. One is the "app", the other one a "lib" which is used in the app. Now, I want to somehow build the lib and use the fresh build within app *without* publishing it to the global npm registry. Thats what I used yarn link for quite often. However, I wonder if pnpm offers me a way to "publish to local store".

So my question: Is it possible to publish build packages to the local pnpm repo in such a way, that "pnpm install lib" within the "app" will successfully install the fresh built "lib" package?

Comment: "publish to local store" sounds like what `yalc` does.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are three ways.

You may use the file protocol to reference your local lib:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "lib": "file:../lib"
  }
}
```

In this case, pnpm will create hard links to each file of lib. It will look like lib is copied to the node_modules of your app.

You may use the link protocol:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "lib": "link:../lib"
  }
}
```

In this case, pnpm will create a symlink to your lib in `app/node_modules/lib`.

Or you may pack your lib into a tarball with `pnpm pack` and then install it through the file protocol

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "lib": "file:../lib/lib-1.0.0.tgz"
  }
}
```

There is no way to "publish to a local store".

Comment: So one has to edit package.json directly? Isn't all this bad for git, though?

Comment: I guess, you still need to test your changes with the unlinked package before pushing the changes. So, it will be an additional reminder to revert your changes before commit.

Comment: Is there another way in 2023? `pnpm link` doesn't override the one defined in `package.json`. it still tries to install the one on the json. Also I can't seem to disable running post install when I try the `link` protocol.

Answer (score 3):

With this context :

- /home/projects/myapp : local git repo of myapp, containing in its dependencies `"mylib": "https://mygitlab.tld/team/mylib.git"`
- /home/projects/mylib : local git repo of mylib

I want to dev mylib with local live testing in myapp, without changing myapp:package.json dependencies.

To achieve this, in /home/projects/myapp I run `pnpm link ../mylib` => /home/projects/myapp/node_modules/mylib is now symlinked to /home/projects/mylib (instead of /home/projects/myapp/node_modules/.pnpm/mygitlab.tld+team+mylib…), so a pnpm start launched in /home/projects/myapp have a hot reload working fine on each change in /home/projects/mylib.

It works even if mylib name isn't `mylib`, if its name is `@myteam/lib` in its package.json, then the `pnpm link ../mylib` will symlink /home/projects/myapp/node_modules/@myteam/lib to /home/projects/mylib

To have the same result, you can also make the link global (register your local copy in your local pnpm store then using it)

- in `/home/projects/mylib` run `pnpm link --global`
- in `/home/projects/myapp` run `pnpm link --global mylib` (if mylib name is @myteam/lib it should be `pnpm link --global @myteam/lib`)

Using this way can be easier if mylib is used in many places and you want to switch quickly from a mylib git worktree to another one (just have to run `pnpm link --global` in the mylib dir you want to use, without having to relink all uses of it).